# Average Bhattacharyya distance

Tags: probability, integration

Two conditional PDF's $f_1(y|X=x)\sim N(Ax,\sigma^2)$ and $f_2(y|X=x)\sim N(-Ax,\sigma^2)$ are given. I need  to find their average Bhattacharyya parameter assuming $X$ has a Rayleigh distribution $$f(x)=\frac{x}{s^2}e^{-x^2/2s^2}$$ for $x\ge 0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x<0$, i.e., need to find the integral
$$
\Delta=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{f_1(y)f_2(y)}\,dy
$$
where $f_i(y)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f_i(y|x)f(x)\,dx$ for $i=1,2$. I have tried Mathematica with no success. Does there exist a closed form solution for $\Delta$?

Comment: I'm not confident this can be done analytically.  You are trying to integrate square roots of error functions.  There is some symmetry, so for that, the integral is worth exploring.  But I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: An upper bound for $\Delta$ in terms of $A,\sigma,s$ is also appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to compute $f_1(y)$ and $f_2(y)$ analytically?